# Speed up the code in NumPy

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have two dimensional numpy array (raster_data) with raster size of 1 million * 1 million.
I want to classify that raster into two classes as follows:

```
class_A = np.where((raster_data >= 5.23) & (raster_data < 8.55),raster_data,np.nan)
class_B = np.where((raster_data >= 8.55) & (raster_data < 10.0),raster_data,np.nan)
```

However, due to extremely large size of the data I receive Memory error.
How can I still classify that raster as I wanted?
I have already tried with 16GB RAM and 64bit NumPy.

Comment: Why is the title speed when the problem is memory?

Comment: An array of 1e6 x 1e6 items has a trillion (1e12) items. Even if you stored a single bit per item, you would need 125 GB **simply to store your `raster_data` array**, with single precision floats you need 4 TB of memory...

Comment: The answer depends on what you are going to do with the classes, how many elements are in the classes (sparse matrix?), and how you store the data.

Comment: Is the data sparse somehow? How are you getting 1M*1M image in the first place? As others have there is something odd about having images this size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try boolean indexing and in-place operations to conserve memory:

```
>>> class_A = raster_data.copy()
>>> class_B = raster_data.copy()
>>> mask = raster_data < 5.23
>>> mask |= raster_data >= 8.55
>>> class_A[mask] = np.nan
>>> mask = raster_data < 8.55
>>> mask |= raster_data >= 10
>>> class_B[mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: No, the `mask` here is the negation of the condition in the OP's question: he is choosing where to keep `raster_data` values, I am looking for where to repalce values by `np.nan`. Notice also that instead of `&`-ing both conditions, I am `|-`ing them, since `~(a & b) == ~a | ~b`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you could do it with pytables. Although i hope you're patient and have lots of space.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np
import time

f = tb.openFile('humongusFile.h5', 'w')

n = 100000
x = f.createCArray(f.root, 'x', tb.Float16Atom(), (n,n), filters=tb.Filters(5, 'blosc'))



t0 = time.time()

for i in range(n):
    x[i] = np.random.random_sample(n)* 10
x.flush()  # dump data to disk

t1 = time.time()
print t1 - t0
print "Done creating test data"

y1 = f.createCArray(f.root, 'y1', tb.Float16Atom(), (n,n), filters=tb.Filters(5, 'blosc'))
y2 = f.createCArray(f.root, 'y2', tb.Float16Atom(), (n,n), filters=tb.Filters(5, 'blosc'))

t2 = time.time()
print t2 - t1
print "Done creating output array"

expr = tb.Expr("where((x >= 5.23) & (x < 8.55), x, 0)")
expr.setOutput(y1)

expr2 = tb.Expr("where((x >= 5.23) & (x < 8.55), x, 0)")
expr2.setOutput(y2)

t3 = time.time()
print t3 - t2
print "Starting evaluating first output"
expr.eval()
print "Starting evaluating second output"
expr2.eval()
print "Done"
t4 = time.time()
print t4 - t3
```

Comment: Your implementation with PyTables is really nice, but is not it possible to use np.nan value in the place of zero in your expression?

Comment: @rockpy I'm not sure if PyTables support nan values. But you can often just "define" a value that should never come up in your data as a nan.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is indeed as insanely large as you specified, you will need some form of on disk storage, and out-of-core computation.

It all depends on what exactly you want to do with that mask, but take a look at pytables; it allows for the efficient storage and manipulation of such large arrays.